# Pure function in assembly language on a Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, assembly

Fibonacci sequence is a great 'hello-world' app when starting with a new language. I want to make a pure machine program that will execute just that, without wasting any resources on intermediary VM, unnecessary memory management, etc.

The best solution is writing down an assembly code and compile it to native binaries. But I've never worked with Assembly language, so what is the best place to start from?

I'm using iMac 64-bit dual-core x86 system.

Comment: A C program compiles down to (more or less) the same code as an assembly language program, so why not just write the program in C? Really there is not much point in learning a specific assembly language, but there is much to be said about learning how the computer works in general (which will involve learning assembly and/or "machine" language), so depending on what your goals are the answer could be quite different.

Comment: @user786653 Not true. Compiled C programs have a lot of runtime library overhead (in size, if not performance): http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: Well, that's why I wrote "more or less", and besides nobody is forcing you to link to any sort of runtime library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fun working with assembly language and it's a great way to learn more about the internal machinery. I am not sure you are wasting that many resources using objective-c for  computing the fibonacci sequence but maybe you can prove me wrong.

To learn assembly start with something really simple and then add more functions and inputs and outputs to understand the system calls and function call sequences and then get more creative.

Be sure to document each line as it's hard maintaining assembly.

For Mac OS X

Create a file called simple.asm :-

```
; simple.asm - exit

section .text

global simple                ; make the main function externally visible

simple:
    mov eax, 0x1              ; system call number for exit
    sub esp, 4                ; OS X (and BSD) system calls needs "extra space" on stack
    int 0x80                  ; make the system call
```

Compile and Link it :-

```
nasm -f macho simple.asm
ld -o simple -e simple simple.o
```

Run it :-

```
asm $ ./simple 
asm $ echo $?
1
```

There are a lot of free resources online for x86 assembly as well as the intel 64-bit specific details.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Have a look at resources for system calls for the bsd kernel and mach kernel for osx specific system calls.

http://osxbook.com

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html

http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/assembly-hello-world-for-os-x

Have a look at linkers and loaders if you want to create libraries.

Comment: Do note that the `int 0x80` (and `sysenter`) syscall interfaces on Mac OS X are officially undocumented, and may change (although, to be fair, they're quite unlikely to do so). The wrappers in `libSystem` are the officially supported API.